# Flatlist won't show images from json (React Native)

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

i've been having this issue with my images not showing in my application.

Im using FlatList:
[image: colors.js]

Here is my javascript file holding the json which im importing into the View:
[image: json file]

I've been trying so many ways to get the Image component to accepts the images but its just not showing, many of the ways i've been trying doesn't show as an error, the images is just not showing at all.

Hope someone can help me out of this dilemma, been stuck for days and googling as a mad man -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems in your code:

1. you need to use `require` instead of `{ uri: '' }` for local images
2. when you use `require` you can't pass a variable as path, so you need to pass just literal string.

So replace each path line in your colors array to include `require`

example:

```
{
  id: 1,
  path: require('../../assets/character-customs/albert/colors/c1.png'),
}
```

Also update `Image` component line with this

```
<Image style={styles.images} source={item.path} />
```

This should work for you

Comment: I did try that. Problem is, im getting an error when doing that.
Error: Invalid call at line 22: require(item.path)

Comment: yeah thats correct `require` will not accept variable you need to pass literal string, i updated the answer, this should work for you

Comment: Don't forget to replace source to be `source={item.path}` as mentioned in answer

Comment: Nope, still not showing :/. It's very strange cause when i console.log(item) im getting the correct paths has i need but getting the images to show in the application just seems near impossible.. Not sure why nothing will work.

Comment: Are you sure that the path is correct i mean ../../ ? I am sure that code should work because this is how i usually do it ... start playing with path make sure that images exist in that path

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/X59QGaZ
Pretty sure its the right path. Screens is where i do my render() method and components - characters.js is where my json is located.

Comment: Final thing i would try is remove style not sure what you currently have in style just try

Comment: Hahaha.... you have got to be kiddin me :D Removed all styling as you said and it works -.- Why havn't i thought of that :D Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

For me flatlist was wrapping all data inside item so this fixed the problem for me

```
 <Image source={{uri:item.path}}/>
```

if this doesnt work try to log item from from renderitem method